# What is the meaning of this proof?

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-explanation

[image]

My teacher wrote this proof for why $-(r.m)=(-r).m$. It may seem simple but I am having real touble understanding it and I don't like just memorising thing. Does anyone understand how to get that last line from the first four?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to State the axioms you are working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that he meant:

$$-(r\cdot m)\stackrel{\text{def.}}=(-1)(r\cdot m)\stackrel{\text{assoc. mult.}}=((-1)\cdot r)\cdot m\stackrel{\text{Def.}}=(-r)\cdot m$$

Another way I propose you: by definition, $\;-(rm)\;$ is the additive inverse of $\;rm\;$ . We shall prove that *also* $\;(-r)m\;$ is an additive inverse for $\;rm\;$ , so by uniqueness of add. inverse we'll get equality:

$$(-r)m+rm\stackrel{\text{Distribut.}}=((-r)+r)m\stackrel{\text{meaning of inverse}}=0\cdot m\stackrel{\text{Hopefully already known}}=0$$

and thus $\;-(rm)=(-r)m\;$

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines prove that:
$$
-(r\cdot m)=(-r)\cdot m
$$
the other lines prove that we have also:
$$
r\cdot(-m)=(-r)\cdot m
$$

so that, by transitivity of the identity,:
$$
r\cdot(-m)=(-r)\cdot m= -(r\cdot m)
$$